# Unable to format number due to error The specified value "798,789.00" is not a valid number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, numbers

I am getting an error when trying to format a number:

> The specified value "798,789.00" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+.\d+|.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?

```
 <FormField
    type="number"
    value={
      Number(
        startupFourthStepForm.previous_investments &&
          startupFourthStepForm.previous_investments[index] &&
          startupFourthStepForm.previous_investments[index].amount,
      )
        .toFixed(2)
        .replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,') || ''
    }
  />
```

I am using `Number` since `amount` comes as a string.
I am getting that error and I am not getting anything to render.

If I remove that regular expression and the `toFixed` method, I get `798789.00` in the input.

What am I missing?

Comment: number input can't have commas. Some browsers may support locale on the input.

Comment: Hi @epascarello can you provide an example of locale?

Comment: If you want to use commas, you will need to us a text input.

Comment: @Non Are you just trying to format the number for readability purposes?

Comment: Hi @JohnRuddell nope. it is a text input on an edit field. So the user could edit that number too.

Comment: Thats fine, but for readability you want to "mask" the input to show a formatted number?

Comment: So basically you should use [**something like this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2901298/2733506). On change you would need to strip commas and `parseInt` to get the number value again